# Setting UILabel to Null value causing exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am attempting to set my UILabel text property and getting the exception NSInvalidArgumentException reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2591068

After doing some debugging I can see that the value I am trying to set is , but I don't understand why this is an issue.  It seems to be related to how NULL is returned in my database results vs. in the object.    Here is the background.

////////

ContactsModel - This is my object that is populated with results from NSArray from the database.

```
#import "ContactModel.h"

@implementation ContactModel


@synthesize contactId;
@synthesize status;
@synthesize phone1;
@synthesize thumb_url;
@synthesize fullname;
@synthesize phone2;

- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.thumb_url = nil;
    self.status = nil;
    self.fullname = nil;
    self.phone1 = nil;
    self.phone2 = nil;
}
return self;
}
```

///////View Controllers

**List View**. - The list view passes the populated object to the detail view through the segue below.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushContactDetail"])
{
    GlobalVars * sharedGlobalVars = [GlobalVars sharedGlobalVars];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.imageCollection indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    ContactDetail *detailView = (ContactDetail *) segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *index = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%d", index.section * 2 + index.row);
    //TODO:  Figure out what the hell this means
    ContactModel *contact =[sharedGlobalVars.contactsContent objectAtIndex:index.section   * 2 + index.row];
    detailView.contact = contact;
}
```

**Detail View** - Assigns the object to the UI in this method

```
- (void) loadContent
{
ImageCache *imgCache = [ImageCache sharedImageCache];
//publisherPhone1.text = self.contact.phone1;
publisherPhone2.text = self.contact.phone2;   //THIS NOT WORKING IF NULL
publisherFullName.text = self.contact.fullname;
UIImage *image = [imgCache getCachedImage:self.contact.thumb_url];
publisherImage.image = image;

}
```

When I output the value of the object here is an example of what I get

```
The value of phone2: <null>
```

If I change my load content method to set self.contact.phone2 = nil for testing purposes everything is fine.  This is what is leading me to think there is a difference and issue between  and nil.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Can you give us the types of all the properties in the ContactModel object? Are they NSString*?

Comment: Someone somewhere has (re)defined `Nil` as `[NSNull null]`, which is not the same thing as `nil`.  (`Nil` should be defined, per objc.h, to be essentially the same as `nil` -- a null pointer.)  Don't use `Nil` in your environment unless and until you figure out how it's been mucked up and you fix that.

Comment: Note that you may get an NSNull object from certain interfaces, particularly database and JSON interfaces.  To test for NSNull compare the pointer value to `[NSNull null]` with `==`.  (Since `[NSNull null]` is a singleton the `==` compare is perfectly adequate.)

Comment: All ContactModel properties are strings yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://nshipster.com/nil/) describes difference between nil, Nil, and NSNull. Enjoy.

P.S.

> self.contact.phone2 = nil;

will be better, I gues.

Comment: I corrected my example above.  I am not settiing self.contact.phone2 to nil in my code.  When I do that everything works.  What I am trying to do is ensure that I don't have to check for nil values before setting my text lable.text value.  Perhaps is something I can handle in the model??  thx for your comments.